# Samsung galaxy note 4 your device is not compatible this version issue in play store

Tags: java, android

Device is not compatibility issue in play store please help thanks

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.



-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="213"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="false" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:name="com.test.application.NYAutoGiantApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/x-cbz" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xps" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cbz" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WestburyToyotaActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/googlemapkey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />

    <!-- Google Analytics Version v4 needs this value for easy tracking -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
        android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />

    <activity
        android:name=".fragments.MyWebViewFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_my_web_view" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: @323go the question is implicit in the title: what aspect of this manifest triggers the store to declare incompatibility?

Comment: Maybe you have ESP, @ChrisStratton... but this statement would be impossible to find when searching, the way it is.

Comment: It's not stated because it is so *obvious* as to be unecessary.  We have a problem statement.  We have a file which causes it. Do you really require explicit wording to connect the two?  This is actually a good question, as the poster included all the necessary information right from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you include a `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"`. I do not believe the note 4 has a smallest width of 600 or more.

Also from the looks of it you just want your app to work with all devices. I believe you can just leave out the `<supports-screens>` and `<compatible-screens>` sections entirely then.